# aria calendar control not working after bundling aria scripts

Tags: c#, wai-aria

I am trying to implement aria calendar control. Desired functionality is that calendar should pop up when I navigate to the calendar button and press enter. Then, I should be able to select the date using up and down arrow keys on the keyboard - pressing enter should select the date and display in my textbox.

This is implemented in the demo by Whatsock - https://whatsock.com/tsg/Coding%20Arena/ARIA%20Date%20Pickers/ARIA%20Date%20Picker%20(Basic)/demo.htm

Now my project is an MVC project and I am trying to bundle the aria calendar js scripts in my bundle.config. However, the tab-enter keyboard functionality refuses to work when scripts are added in bundle. It works perfectly fine when the scripts are added separately on the page itself. Is this a limitation of aria calendar control - or am I implementing it incorrectly?